# About MicrosoftMediaTool

Tags: windows

I'll go for a Windows 10 Pro Re-Installation via MicrosoftMediaTool20H2 (with a USB stick/installation media). I've read all the things you should know before doing this. I understood all of them, but I still have some questions just to be sure it'll be ok at the process. Also my digital license is linked to my Microsoft account, so after the re-installation it's easy to activate Windows, by just signing in to my Microsoft account.

My question is: Is it possible for Windows to mess it up and install Windows 10 Home to my laptop, instead of Windows 10 Pro? Because my lisence is linked with my account in Windows 10 Pro.

Moreover, a month ago I switched to SSD and I put HDD on the caddy, as a secondary drive. I don't think this will be a problem. Because I want to keep all the apps and files from both drives (the only thing I want to re-install is Windows 10 Pro).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: Is it possible for Windows to mess it up and install
> Windows 10 Home to my laptop, instead of Windows 10 Pro? Because my
> lisence is linked with my account in Windows 10 Pro.

No, the Repair will not mess up. If your license is for Windows 10 Pro, the Repair Install will most certainly leave you with Windows 10 Pro.

To your second question, changing from Hard Drive to SSD. That works fine as well. No issue because of the Windows 10 licensing with the Microsoft Licensing server.

Before you start, shut down, remove the Hard Drive carrier entirely, start up the machine and make sure start up is correct.  Assuming it is, you are good to go.

I have done all of the above including shift to SSD.

Comment: If some error occures I'll send here. I'm ready to do this, starting with the caddy:P! Thanks for the reply!

Comment: You are very welcome and I hope it all works well for you.

Comment: Last questions: After installation is complete I assume I can take out the usb stick (right?)...And also, if it asks about a product key I skip it, and simply login to my Microsoft account to re-activate Windows 10 Pro, right...?

Comment: Yes, just log in and Windows 10 will be fine. I have not had any issue with this.

Comment: I know but I'm a bit scared. I think everything will be fine tho, because I put architecture, language and winver right at the beggining (and I keep all my files as well). I'll let you know when it's all done!

Comment: I'm back it's all done without any errors! I didn't have to put my Microsoft account it was ready! And the license already activated with my account!!!!!!

Comment: Good news . Thanks.

Comment: Last question because an error occured and account settings do not open. If I do a clean install right now from the usb, it's the same thing right? I mean I won't have a problem with the account and activation? I'm asking this because the error may occured because I kept my files and settings and now says I'm not the administrator. So a clean install will help I think...

Comment: Make sure you back up, but a clean (fresh) install is always the final step.

Comment: I did it with success problem solved! Thank you again!